# How to output an array as actions in a Deep Reinforcement Learning Model?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I am currently working on a custom multiagent DQN environment and my action_space is a list, for example [2,4,3,2,1].

Where actionlist[0] is the action taken by the first agent, actionlist[1] is an action taken by the second and so and so forth.

Normally for a single value output, the codes will look like this:

```
states = env.observation_space.shape
actions = env.action_space.n

def build_model(states, actions):
    model = Sequential()    
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu', input_shape=states))
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(actions, activation='linear'))
    return model

...some model building

def build_agent(model, actions):
    policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()
    memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1)
    dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy=policy, 
                  nb_actions=actions, nb_steps_warmup=10, target_model_update=1e-2)
    return dqn
```

However , this doesn't work with an output that is not a single value.

How do go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know that there are two types of action space problem (discrete and continuous) and there are two types of reinforcement learning method (1.value-based and 2.policy or policy/value based).

DQN is value based reinforcement learning method, which calculates the value for each discrete action at any given state vector. Therefore, it is only designed for discrete action space problem (e.g., action can on be one value in a vector [1,2,3]).

"not a single value" action in your description is a continuous action space problem, where your action can be any possible value at a given range (e.g., 2.0120321 in the range of [0,10]). For the continuous action space problem, you need to use policy based reinforcement learning method, such as Actor-Critic and other popular frameworks built on top of actor-critic such as PPO, DDPG, etc.

I suggest you to get some basic ideas of reinforcement learning by reading the most popular text book in this area (Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction) from Richard Sutton: https://web.stanford.edu/class/psych209/Readings/SuttonBartoIPRLBook2ndEd.pdf